# PostgresQL: can sum(f1) - sum(f2) be null if f1 and f2 are not null

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose we have a table in postgres database with type and two numeric fields.

```
select type, sum(f1) - sum(f2) as delta
from table
group by type
```

Is it possible to have delta to be null if both f1 and f2 are not null for all rows in the table?

Comment: What exactly is the point of this question?

Comment: I am having it null on production server but cannot access the data (due to security reasons). The point is to emulate the issue with fake data.

Comment: yes, they have NOT NULL constraint

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't have access to the data anymore as it is secured. I think the database host owner could alter the constraint and one of the fields is null.

Comment: Not entirely sure about PostgreSQL, but it is possible to do on SQL Server by forcing the database to ignore overflow errors.  You can execute `SET ARITHABORT OFF; SET ARITHIGNORE ON; SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF; SELECT 2147483647, 2147483647 + 1` and you'd get a NULL result with no warning or error at all.

Comment: This could be only NULL if **all** `f1` or `f2` are NULL within a `type` and as both columns are `NOT NULL` the only reason might be an `OUTER JOIN`